# How do I complete this prove of $\Phi$ is linear and symplectic iff its graph is a Lagrangian subspace of $(V \times V,(−\omega) \oplus \omega)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $(V, \omega)$ be a symplectic vector space. Prove that a map $\Phi :
V \mapsto V $is linear and symplectic if and only if its graph
$\{(v, \Phi v)| v \in V\}$
is a Lagrangian subspace of $V \times V$ , equipped with the symplectic form $(−\omega) \oplus \omega$.

$(\Leftarrow)$

If G is Lagrangian then,  $(−\omega) \oplus \omega=0 $ on G $\iff 0 = ((−\omega) \oplus \omega)((v,\Phi(v)),(v',\Phi(v')))=-\omega(v,v')+w(\Phi(v),\Phi(v')),   \forall v,v'  \in V $

$\iff \omega(v,v')=w(\Phi(v),\Phi(v'))$ which is the definition of symplectic map

For the linearity: $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}; v,v'\in V \implies $

$\omega(\Phi(\alpha v+\beta v'),\Phi w )=\omega(\alpha v+\beta v',w)=\alpha\omega(v,w) +\beta \omega(v',w)=\omega(\alpha \Phi v +\beta \Phi v',\Phi w)$

$\omega(\Phi(\alpha v+\beta v') - (\alpha \Phi v +\beta \Phi v'),\Phi w )=0, \forall v,w\in V$

I would like to conclude that the left argument is 0 due to the non degeneracy of $\omega$, but I am unsure if I can do that, since I have $\Phi w$ as second argument instead of just $w$. I mean, if I had  $\omega(\Phi(\alpha v+\beta v') - (\alpha \Phi v +\beta \Phi v'), w )=0, \forall v,w\in V$, I'd be done with linearity
**How do I conclude from here ?
and how do I prove the other implication $(\Rightarrow)$ ?**

Possible solution: I use that a subspace G is Lagragian if $G=G^\omega$

Let $\Phi$ be linear and symplectic
Let $(v,\Phi v),(v',\Phi v')\in G \implies (v,\Phi v)+(v',\Phi v')=(v+v',\Phi(v+v'))\in G$, so $G$ is a linear subspace of $V \times V$

$G^\omega =\{(v,v')\in V\times V|((-\omega)\oplus\omega)((v,v'),(w,w'))=0 \forall (w,w') \in G\} =\{(v,v')\in V\times V| \omega(v',w')-\omega(v,w)=0 \forall (w,w') \in G\}=\{(v,v')\in V\times V| \omega(v',\Phi(w))-\omega(v,w)=0 \forall w \in V\}=\{(v,v')\in V\times V| \omega(v',\Phi(w))=\omega(\Phi(v),\Phi(w))=0 \forall w \in V\}$

In particular the equality inside the set  also holds $\forall w=v$, so

$=\{(v,v')\in V\times V| \omega(v',\Phi(v))=\omega(\Phi(v),\Phi(v))=0 \forall v \in V\} =\{(v,\Phi(v))\in V\times V| v \in V\} = G$

However I am a bit unsure specially about the last part, when I set $w=v$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v,v',w \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. On the one hand,
\begin{align}
\alpha\omega(v,w)+\omega(v',w) & = \alpha \omega(\Phi(v),\Phi(w)) + \omega(\Phi(v'),\Phi(w)) \\
&  = \omega(\alpha \Phi(v) +\Phi(v'),\Phi(w))
\end{align}
using that $\Phi$ is symplectic and the bilinearity of $\omega$. On the other hand,
\begin{equation}
\alpha\omega(v,w) + \omega(v',w)=\omega(\alpha v+ v',w) = \omega(\Phi(\alpha v+v'),\Phi(w)).
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\omega(\Phi(\alpha v+v'),\Phi(w)) = \omega(\alpha \Phi(v) +\Phi(v'),\Phi(w)) \quad \forall v,v',w \in V,
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\alpha v+v') = \alpha \Phi(v) +\Phi(v').
\end{equation}

For the converse, note that the graph of $\Phi$ is an isotropic subspace of $V\times V$ since
\begin{align}
(-\omega \oplus \omega)((v,\Phi(v)),(w,\Phi(w))) & = -\omega(v,w)+\omega(\Phi(v),\Phi(w)) \\
& = -\omega(v,w)+\omega(v,w) \\
& = 0
\end{align}
for all $(v,\Phi(v)),(w,\Phi(w))$ in the graph of $\Phi$. Then consider a map $V\to V\times V$ given by $v\mapsto (v,\Phi(v))$. It is clearly injective and by rank-nullity the dimension of $V$ equals the dimension of the image of this map, which is precisely the graph of $\Phi$. Obviously $\dim V = \frac{1}{2} \dim (V\times V)$ so the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, liked the last part. I also added another way to do it in my post, could you check if that works too? I am a bit unsure

Comment: No it does not work, because while you're saying `the equality inside the set is equal for all $w =v$', you are actually picking just only one $w$, namely $w=v$.